# Determine if a piece of text is a job ad

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am interested in learning more about the field of ML and more specifically in text classification.

Given a piece of text, is there any technique or algorithm to determine if that piece of text refers to a job ad or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, a binary classifier. One simple method is to train an RNN using pretrained word embeddings to deal with the variable lenght. If you have ancillary information about the text's provenance or formatting, you can incorporate that too by augmenting the word embedding features. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

For text classification in your case, it can be solved by training a binary classes classification network.
Main steps as follows:

**1. Training data preparation**

Two classes data are needed, one class contain job ad text, and the other does not contain job ad.

**2. Building the network**

Building a binary classification network with Keras, Caffe or any other DL library you like.

**3. Train the network**

Training the network on the data prepared above.

**4. Text class prediction**

Use the trained network to predict the text class you want to deal with.

It’s a easy classification task for neural network: )

Answer (score 0):

In case the con(text) is not too complex, you will not necessarily need a neural net to classify the text. Often a simple „bag of words“ with a ridge regression will do the job. This is more efficient (less code, less tuning).

Find a minimal example of (binary) text classification here: https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/NLP_regression_bag_of_words.R